# Fatal error with loading the personal dataset

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to run this code for extraction of deep features and prediction of class and I have no idea how I can change it with my personal dataset.

Please, if anyone had this code, let me know how you did it.

Thanks.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
model.layers.pop()
model = Model(input=model.input,output=model.layers[-1].output)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9), metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

```
# Change with my dataset
from data_gen import PascalVOCDataGenerator
data_dir = '/data/VOCdevkit/VOC2007/' # A changer avec votre chemin
data_generator_train = PascalVOCDataGenerator('trainval', data_dir)
```

How I can change this 3 last rows (Pascal database) with my personal dataset.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to describe your dataset, else nobody can answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My dataset is a folder of images.